# Alternative to Variable Variables in PHP

Tags: php, loops, variables, foreach

In this loop, i am iterating through an array and performing an API call each time. This works fine but I keep reading that using variable variables is not good practice. How could I rewrite this code without using them?

edit: I am not using an array because I have to pass the variables into another template along has other variables outside that array.

`template( 'template-name', [ 'graphOne' => $graphOne, 'graphTwo' => $graphTwo, 'outsideVar' => $anothervalue ] );`

```
<?php 

// Array of categories for each graph
$catArray = [
    'One'   => '3791741',
    'Two'   => '3791748',
    'Three' => '3791742',
    'Four'  => '3791748'
];

foreach ( $catArray as $graphNum => $cat )
{
        // Hit API
        $graph_results = theme( 'bwatch_graph_call', [
                'project'  => '153821205',
                'category' => $cat
            ]
        );

        ${"graph{$graphNum}"} = $graph_results;
        // Outputs $graphOne, $graphTwo, $graphThree...

}

// Pass vars to template
template( 'template-name', [ 
'graphOne' => $graphOne,
'graphTwo' => $graphTwo,
'outsideVar' => $anothervalue ] 
);
```

Comment: Use another array to keep the results: `$graph[$graphNum] = $graph_results;`

Comment: You could have an array? Something like `$graphs = [];` before your `foreach` and then assign `$graphs[$graphNum] = $graph_results;`

Comment: Any particular reason  for not using an array? And if you really need those variables, you might want to have a look at this http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

Comment: I am not using an array because I have to pass the variables into another template that also has other variables. `template( 'template-name', [ 'graphOne' => $graphOne, 'graphTwo' => $graphTwo, 'outsideVar' => $anothervalue ] );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PHP's `array_merge` when you make your `template()` call if you have multiple arrays with different key=>value pairs.

http://php.net/array_merge

Here is an example if you have multiple arrays (key=>value pairs) you want to pass to the template.

```
// Array of categories for each graph
$catArray = [
    'One'   => '3791741',
    'Two'   => '3791748',
    'Three' => '3791742',
    'Four'  => '3791748'
];

// Array of category results
$catResult = [];

foreach ( $catArray as $graphNum => $cat )
{
        // Hit API
        $catResult['graph' . $graphNum] = theme( 'bwatch_graph_call', [
                'project'  => '153821205',
                'category' => $cat
            ]
        );
}

// Now you have an array of results like...
// $catResult['graphOne'] = 'result for One';
// $catResult['graphTwo'] = 'result for Two';

$otherArray1 = ['outsideVar' => $anothervalue];

$otherArray2 = ['somethingElse' => $oneMoreValue];

// Pass all arrays as one
template('template-name', array_merge($catResult, $otherArray1, $otherArray2));
```